# Prolog retrieving data from a knowledge base and arithmetic operation

Tags: prolog

Hi this is a question I ran into when I was going through some question sets. The knowledge base is given with the following information,

> **boat(Boat_ID, Boat_name, color,fare_per_passenger)**

The question says to write a procedure to do the following,

> to obtain the boat identification number together with the fare per
>   passenger increased by 5%.

I wrote the procedure as,

```
boat(BID,_,_,F), F is F*1.05.
```

Prolog keeps returning me with a message saying **false** any idea?

Comment: You cannot change a variable in Prolog. Use something other than F where you have `F is`

Comment: `F is F * 1.05` says, in Prolog, that the value of `F` is the same as the value of `F * 1.05` which obviously is always false except when `F` has the value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was,

```
boat(BID,_,_,F), Nfare is F*1.05.
```

the issue was with using the same variable for the arithmetic operation as well.

Credit to Daniel Lyons for mentioning it.

Comment: 1. `nFare` is not a valid Prolog variable name, because it does not begin with an upper case letter. So this will not work. 2. My last name does not have two 'o's in it.